# Expand the limitation of linux samba share folder across partitions

Tags: centos, samba, quota

I have an issue when sharing the Linux data via smb as below:

- I have a few partitions in some HDDs (e.g 100G in HDD1 */media/shared/HDD1*, 200G in HDD2 as */media/shared/HDD2*)
- The smb config is set to share the parent folder (*path = /media/shared*)
- Then the above share folder is mounted in another PC
- **The issue is**: the total size of the share folder is only 49G, it causes the big size file (>=50G) cannot be copied as the OS sees full disk. (df -h in remote PC: *user@shared_pc:/media/shared   50G   28G   19G  60% /media/remote_PC*)
- When a single partition is shared, the total size of share folder can be seen as full size (*user@shared_pc:/media/shared/HDD1   100G   48G   51G  48% /media/remote_PC_HDD1*)

I would like to know if there is a way to share full size of the total folder (e.g 100G HDD1 + 200G HDD2 show as 300G), could anyone help?

Many thanks

Comment: If they are already partitions I don´t think this is possible. If you can use that free space and create new partitions, you can add them together using logical volumes and then share with samba the logical volume. This is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks @LincolnP for your reply. So I assumed the 49G is the hardcoded limitation value of samba configuration in this case, and separate partition is the only way to do.